# What is a tardigrade "in tun form"?

Tags: definitions

While reading [this article](http://news.discovery.com/animals/frozen-animal-brought-back-to-life-after-30-years-160121.htm) about tardigrades that had been previously frozen, I came across some verbiage I wasn't sure of and couldn't find any real explanation given the context. The article kept making mention of the tardigrades *"in **tun** form"*, yet the only references I could find to the meaning of `tun` dealt with weight or casks (like for holding liquid).

So does *tun* mean `cask` (like a casing) in this context?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing for a good long while, but I have come to the same conclusion that tuns are a folded-up version of the tardigrade that slows down the metabolism of the creature. >>>Tardigrades are microscopic, yet almost invincible one-celled organisms.-Anonymous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Illinois Wesleyan University](https://sun.iwu.edu/~tardisdp/tardigrade_facts.html):

> One way in which tardigrades have adapted to various types of
>   environments, has been to reversibly suspend their metabolism. This
>   state is known as **cryptobiosis** [ '*hidden life*' [(Clegg, 2001)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11290443) ] and is a truly deathlike state.
>   Metabolism lowers to 0.01% of normal or is entirely undetectable and
>   the water content of the body decreases to less than 1%. [...]
>
> The most intensely studied type of cryptobiosis is anhydrobiosis, a
>   form of cryptobiosis initiated by desiccation. [...] Anhydrobiosis is an almost complete
>   loss of body water and the animal can stay in this state for an
>   extended period of time. **Tun formation**, a vital part of the process [Fig. 1.],
>   results in a body that is **constricted and folded**. The first step is
>   **invagination of the limbs**, **longitudinal contraction of the body**, and
>   **infolding of the intersegmental cuticle**. **Wax extrusion** covers the
>   surface and may help to reduce transpiration (water loss by
>   evaporation). The tun formation process requires active metabolism. [...]

[image: Tardigrade tun state]
<sup>Fig. 1. Tardigrade before and after entering the tun state. Note the decreased body length and infoldings. Source: [Media & Society Journal](http://nafasocietyandmedia.blogspot.nl/2015/04/new-discovery-meet-tardigrades-seabear.html).</sup>

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Clegg, *Comp Biochem Physiol B Biochem Mol Biol* (2001); **128**(4): 613-24](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11290443)</sub>